# How can I access a variable from an inner range loop in Helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to pick Sitename value from one of the list with name usa. If there has no name with usa in list, then we need to print else part.

My values files be like below.

```
Hosts:
  - name: usa
    Type:...
    Sitename: localhost
    Port: 443
  - name: Virginia
    Type:...
    Sitename: endhost
    Port: 9093
```

The code i am using is

```
{{- $names := list -}}

{{- if .Values.Hosts }}

{{- range .Values.Hosts }}

{{- $names = append $names .name }}

{{- $hostname := ( .Sitename ) }}

{{- end }}

{{- end }}

{{- if has "usa" $names }}

sdfjsdf: {{ $hostname }}

{{- else }} 

abcd: false 

{{- end }}
```

I need to bring the range $hostname to outer range loop

Please suggest any way to bring the $hostname to outside the range loop.

If any one has any better approach please suggest me that too.